# Unable to enable Organizational Authorization for custom domain in O365 Azure AD

Tags: azure, office365, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I want to publish a web application to a Azure Web App and enable Organizational Authentication during the process. The wizard offers the following options:

[image: options in Publish wizard]

I've added two custom domains to our Office 365 subscription that also show up in the corresponding Azure AD tenant.

Instead of using the default domain `mycompany.onmicrosoft.com` I want to use one  of those custom domains so that this domain is shown to the user on various web pages that handle authentication and consent. I was able to use the custom domain without any problem when configuring Azure AD authentication for the web project.

When using the custom domain in the wizard (field domain in the screenshot), I first need to enter my O365 credentials. Shortly after, the following error is displayed:

> Provisioning the destination end point failed with the error:
>       'The user account 'x@y.z' doesn't have the required permissions to access the domain 'y.z'.'
>
> If you don't intend to enable Orgnizational Authentication during
>   publish, please turn that option off in the publish dialog.

The Directory Role of the account is Global Administrator and I've already registered multiple apps using this account. So I don't think that this has anything to do with permissions.

**Do I have to use the *.onmicrosoft.com domain or can I solve this in a different way?**

As a sidenote (just if this is makes a difference): the web app resides in a Azure subscription that belongs to my Microsoft account whereas the O365 Azure AD is administered by my work account and does not belong to a subscription. Of course, not the most straightforward way, but I guess pretty common for Microsoft partners as the Azure benefits can only be actived on a Microsoft account even if the partner already has a O365 subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the custom domain for the organization authentication we need to enable it as the primary domain.

You can check it from the [old Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) here like figure below:
[image]

### Update( change the primary domain in [new Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/))

locate Azure Active Directory->Domain names->select the domain which want to set as primary domain like figure below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already suspected that. You might want to include details for the new Azure portal because it is impossible to log on to manage.windowsazure.com with a O365 work or school account. There also is the option to make a domain the primary domain in the new portal.